# SVG, Angular - Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, svg

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/svg-donuts-3yfsou?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdonuts.template.html

I have an svg pie chart in an Angular component

The chart sections should be positioned next to each other but the second section 'red' in the wrong place.

I'm also getting the error

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
```

Can anyone explain this error and I imagine this is tht reason the chart isnt working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the missplacement was that you did not correctly implement the formula for the offset and you pushed to previous values before calculation of the current offset.

The reason for the error is that you change the offset for components that are already rendered but rendering has not yet been finished. To get rid of that you should calculate everything before rendering.

I have modified your Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/svg-donuts-ng2c4j

Hope this helps ;-)